# TypeError withstyles is not a function react export default

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to import withstyles from material-ui and then, use the default function withstyles but always have the same error.

```
import { withStyles } from "material-ui/styles/withStyles";
import { loginPageStyle } from "../assets/jss/material-kit-react/views/loginPage.jsx";

export default  withStyles(loginPageStyle)(LoginPage);
```

And here you can see the error. I try to debug with chrome console but can not find any solution yet.

[image: Image display the error]

[image: withsStyles Object]

Using     "material-ui": "1.0.0-beta.45"
That is the loginPageStyle.. It is an example from material-kit

```
import { container } from "../../material-kit-react.jsx";

const signupPageStyle = {
  container: {
    ...container,
    zIndex: "2",
    position: "relative",
    paddingTop: "20vh",
    color: "#FFFFFF"
  },
  cardHidden: {
    opacity: "0",
    transform: "translate3d(0, -60px, 0)"
  },
  pageHeader: {
    minHeight: "100vh",
    height: "auto",
    display: "inherit",
    position: "relative",
    margin: "0",
    padding: "0",
    border: "0",
    alignItems: "center",
    "&:before": {
      background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"
    },
    "&:before,&:after": {
      position: "absolute",
      zIndex: "1",
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      display: "block",
      left: "0",
      top: "0",
      content: '""'
    }
  },
  form: {
    margin: "0"
  },
  cardHeader: {
    width: "auto",
    textAlign: "center",
    marginLeft: "20px",
    marginRight: "20px",
    marginTop: "-40px",
    padding: "20px 0",
    marginBottom: "15px",
  },
  socialIcons: {
    maxWidth: "24px",
    marginTop: "0",
    width: "100%",
    transform: "none",
    left: "0",
    top: "0",
    height: "100%",
    lineHeight: "41px",
    fontSize: "20px"
  },
  divider: {
    marginTop: "30px",
    marginBottom: "0px",
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  cardFooter: {
    paddingTop: "0rem",
    border: "0",
    borderRadius: "6px",
    justifyContent: "center !important"
  },
  socialLine: {
    marginTop: "1rem",
    textAlign: "center",
    padding: "0",
  },
  inputIconsColor: {
    color: "#495057",
  }
};

export default signupPageStyle;
```

Comment: Which Material UI version are you using? Also, which is the content of `loginPageStyle`?

Comment: Updated with loginPageStyle and my version of material-ui @Dez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import like
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

Comment: I did, now I have not the error. But now in my LoginPage when I trie to get the properties classes (that is comming from my imports) is always undefined. I don't know why, but all the props that comes from my imports are undefined.